# Does Quran promote eunuchs by allowing them?

Tags: quran, tafseer

Verse 24:31 tells that women should guard their selves except from the following people:

> ... husbands, their fathers, their husbands' fathers, their sons, their husbands' sons, their brothers, their brothers' sons, their sisters' sons, their women, that which their right hands possess, or **those male attendants having no physical desire**, or children who are not yet aware of the private aspects of women.

I interpreted "male attendants having no physical desire" as eunuchs. Is this correct? If so, doesn't allowing them to guard women effectively promote castration? I understand Islam prohibits castration, but allowing them to guard women promotes the eunuch supply chain. For example, I wouldn't buy something that was stolen because I don't want to promote stealing. Perhaps I would be forgiven for buying something I didn't know was stolen, but it's obvious if someone is castrated.

Comment: Interesting question. I guess it could also mean old man, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Where do you read this in that question? Something which hardly is legal for pets/animal can't be declared legal and promoted for humans. You seem to misunderstand that answer entirely. Some examples are  impotent or feebleminded or old men who either lost the desire or don't have it for whatever reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is absolutely forbidden to change human form . Acceptance of your given body and soul is big part of teachings of Islam . Male attendees that have no physical desire means someone who doesn’t view you as sexual partner - could be so many people that are not mentioned as far as relatives or people who are around you. You could have a great sense who views you sexually or who views you as just a human being. Quran gives women independence to women choose who she can show herself fully to.

As a Muslim damaging any part of your body intentionally or changing your body is a sin. Our bodies are simply a loan that Allah granted us with and to him we shall return . We believe we will be questioned even on what we consume , how we treated our bodies .

I hope that answers your question.

Comment: Makes sense. But eunuchs have been used historically in Islam. They were not castrated, but found to be castrated. Was it permissible to use them?

Comment: Prophet Muhammad (saw ) in his final sermon said that “ there is no superiority over arab and non Arab and no superiority white over black.” We only differ by our conducts and our deeds. 
“ use them” will mean keep them as servants or slaves. Slavery is forbidden in Islam . All men are descendants of Adam and they are equals.